# Nested pass-through queries?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010, pass-through

I have an ODBC connection to a SQL Server database, and because I'm returning large record sets with my queries, I've found that it's faster to run pass-through queries than native Access queries.

But I'm finding it hard to write and organize my queries because, as far as I know, I can't save several different pass-through queries and join them in another pass-through query.  I have read-only access to this database, so I can't save stored procedures in SQL Server and then reference them in the pass-through.

For example, suppose I want to get only those entries with the maximum value of `o_version` from the following query:

```
select d.o_filename,d.o_version,parent.o_projectname
from dms_doc d
left join
dms_proj p
on
d.o_projectno=p.o_projectno
left join
dms_proj parent
on
p.o_parentno=parent.o_projectno
where
p.o_projectname='ABC'
and
lower(left(right(d.o_filename,4),3))='xls'
and
charindex('xyz',lower(d.o_filename))=0
```

I want to get only those entries with the maximum value of `d.o_version`.  Ordinarily I would save this as a query called, e.g., `abc`, and then write another query `abcMax`:

```
select * from abc
inner join
(select o_filename,o_projectname,max(o_version) as maxVersion from abc
 group by o_filename,o_projectname) abc2
on
abc.o_filename=abc2.o_filename
and
abc.o_projectname=abc2.o_projectname
where
abc.o_version=abc2.maxVersion
```

But if I can't store `abc` as a query that can be used in the pass-through query `abcMax`, then not only do I have to copy the entire body of `abc` into `abcMax` several times, but if I make any changes to the content of `abc`, then I need to make them to every copy that's embedded in `abcMax`.

The alternative is to write `abcMax` as a regular Access query that calls `abc`, but that will reduce the performance because the query is now being handled by ACE instead of SQL Server.

Is there any way to nest stored pass-through queries in Access?  Or is creating stored procedures in SQL Server the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have (or can get) permission to create temporary tables on the SQL Server then you might be able to use them to some advantage. For example, you could run one pass-through query to create a temporary table with the results from the first query (vastly simplified, in this example):

```sql
CREATE TABLE #abc (o_filename NVARCHAR(50), o_version INT, o_projectname NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #abc SELECT o_filename, o_version, o_projectname FROM dms_doc;
```

and then your second pass-through query could just reference the temporary table

```sql
select * from #abc
inner join
(select o_filename,o_projectname,max(o_version) as maxVersion from #abc
 group by o_filename,o_projectname) abc2
on
#abc.o_filename=abc2.o_filename
and
#abc.o_projectname=abc2.o_projectname
where
#abc.o_version=abc2.maxVersion
```

When you're finished you can run a pass-through query to explicitly delete the temporary table

```sql
DROP TABLE #abc
```

or SQL Server will delete it for you automatically when your connection to the SQL Server closes.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still needing this info:

Pass through queries allow for the use of cte queries as can be used with Oracle SQL. Similar to creating multiple select queries, but much faster and efficient, without the clutter and confusion of “stacked” Select queries since you can see all the underlying queries in one view.

Example:

```
With Prep AS (

SELECT A.name,A.city

FROM Customers AS A
)

SELECT P.city, COUNT(P.name) AS clients_per_city
FROM Prep AS P
GROUP BY P.city
```